# New mysqli () is reset to null when using a function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, null

I am currently working with mySQL and php to create a web application.
In my main index.php file, I have

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');
require_once('includes/functionName.php');
?>
```

My config.php is as below:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "DB";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected Successfully!";
?>
```

When I call the actual function `functionName("test");`
it goes into the actual functionName.php and goes to

```
$sql = "UPDATE Table SET id = " . $test1 . " WHERE name = \"". $name . "\"";
echo $sql;
var_dump ($conn);
```

This returns `UPDATE Table SET id = 09 WHERE name = "test"` which is correct as an SQL query.
However, my $conn returns `NULL`, and as a result I get FATAL ERROR query on NULL.

Please tell me why my $conn is returning NULL, and failing my query?

Comment: Do you have global $conn in your function?

Comment: Call $conn as a global variable in the function, otherwise you can't access it from inside the function.

Comment: Hi, dont you mean to do the query first and put the result in $conn?

Comment: try to add line **global $conn;** inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you it was solved after adding line `global $conn`